# What does fast but accurate mean?

Tags: phrases

The whole sentence is

> We show that this approximation, when coupled with an active learning
>   strategy, is fast but accurate.

is there a not missing before accurate? Or is the meaning fast and accurate?

Comment: I think the meaning is exactly as stated. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't understand the exactly stated meaning, that's why I ask. I use and know the word but as in contrast/opposite to something being fast but accurate makes no sense to me. Is it both or is it only fast but not accurate? and if it is both why wasn't the word and used?

Comment: The normal expectation is that speed and accuracy are in opposition -- that improving one makes the other worse.  The "but" emphasizes that this expectation does not hold in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, doing things faster implies that something is being sacrificed, for example accuracy. The sentence you posted says that the approximation is fast, *but* it does not suffer from reduced accuracy.

Fast **and** accurate would mean essentially the same thing, but the way it was phrased emphasizes that accuracy is not compromised, contrary to what might be expected.

Comment: I wonder if this sentence wouldn't be clearer with an and. Especially because non english speaker might not be aware of the second meaning of but. And especially because there is such a contrast non english speaker might think there is a not missing.

Comment: @Hakaishin: Anglophones write/speak English with the intention that *other* Anglophones should understand them - they're not normally interested in how easily they might be understood by non-native speakers. It's *possible* to use the conjunction ***and*** rather than ***but*** in your cited context, but this would slightly shift the nuance. Trust me - the writer knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is a trade-off when doing something fast, which involves cutting corners and thus reducing accuracy. In this sentence, the claim is made that despite being fast, it is still accurate.

The use of *approximation* already implies a lack of accuracy, so with *but* this implication is acknowledged. The difference to *fast and accurate* is that it presumes the trade-off, and emphasise that it is not a mistake (ie there is no missing *not*).

Answer (score 0):

*But* has the same literal meaning as *and*. It has also a presupposition of surprise -- the speaker acknowledges a reasonable expectation of a possible  different result.

So, while saying  *fast and accurate* just means 'fast and accurate',
saying *fast **but** accurate* means 'fast and -- surprisingly -- accurate'.